A Vec-like containers of different types that can share the same block of memory on the heap
I'm trying to write a SparseSet implementation that in my case consists of 3 Vecs:
pub struct SparseSet<T> {
    dense_values: Vec<T>,
    dense_keys: Vec<Key>,
    sparse: Vec<SparseEntry>,
    next_free_sparse_entry: usize,
}

I noticed that when the amount of the elements needs to increase, all 3 Vecs have the same size, which means that when they need to increase the memory they allocated, they would likely do that at the same time.
I assume the best-case scenario to reduce allocations would be for them to share the same heap memory block. Then, when they need to grow, allocate a new block of x2 size and let them move their elements to the appropriate parts of this new block, then deallocate the previous block.

However, I'm not sure how I can achieve this in Rust.
Can I do it without using "unsafe"? Are there solutions for this in the standard library?
And if not, what features of unsafe Rust should I look into?

Frankly, do you care? This will likely involve a considerable complixification of your code. Is the cost of allocating once vs. three times noticeable? If yes, then the vectors likely grow too many times, and it's there that you should invest.

Also, do they always have the same size? If yes, you can store them as Vec<(T, Key, SparseEntry)>, which can have other advantages with cache (as well as disadvantages, depending on the access pattern).

Heap use can be costly because it reduces memory locality, but the mere act of allocation only performs a little bookkeeping. Turning three allocations into one does nothing for memory locality, it only moves the bookkeeping work from the allocator (which will now perform it only once) to your own code, which will have to deal with three Vecs somehow sharing the same memory. If you really want to try this, look into an arena allocator comibed with a self-referential crate.

This seems like a bad idea, but fun to build. The mismatch in size between the 3 structs will probably cause alignment issues that will wipe out any performance gains. Please don't do this in production, especially not without benchmarking.
If you want to continue down this path, you will have to use unsafe. Here's a relevant quote from the Nomicon:

You wanted advanced. We're gonna go advanced.

You can create a wrapper around a Vec<MaybeUninit<uXXX>> (where uXXX is an unsigned integer of the right alignment) that checks and unsafely transmutes an array/slice of [uXXX] into your desired T on access. Check out the source code of array_assume_init() and the Nomicon's Implementing Vec for inspiration.

Nice, will check out the links! Yes, at this point I'm more interested to learn how these things are done.
